# Old sets, new bricks

Tags: sets, shopping

Are there sellers out there that compile old discontinued Lego sets with new bricks? In other words they source new bricks and instructions to put together old discontinued sets. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not aware of any sellers that do this, but if you like to assemble discontinued sets, [bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com)
has a feature that allows you to do this using bricklink seller inventories. Just look up the set on bricklink, add the Inventory to your wishlist and review which sellers have the pieces you need, then order them.

Go to the "Wanted" tab on Bricklink: http://www.bricklink.com/wantedAdd.asp
Then select the "Part Set" tab and fill out the item number of the set you are looking for (you might need to do a Catalog search to find out this number). Pick the options you want, check the "Set Minimum Qty" option, and "Submit for Edit". You will now have a broken down list of parts that you can edit (for example, replace original parts with proposed substitutions, this is useful when your set is really old and the original part is difficult to get, but a more current part exists that likely has better availability). Add this to your Wanted List and you're ready to go.

Alternatively, many old, discontinued sets can be bought, in box, on [ebay](http://www.ebay.com) and [bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com), but depending on the rarity and popularity of the set you might be paying a significant premium.