# Buy an specific set of bricks

Tags: shopping, pick-a-brick, bricklink

I have a specific list of bricks for building a LEGO set that I found online, with approximately 300 pieces and around 70 different blocks.

I have seen that one of the best ways for buying LEGOs seems to be Bricklink web page.
However, there are hundreds if not thousands of sellers, and the webpage does not seem to be designed to add a list and search for sellers or something like that.

Has anyone been in my situation? How would you buy an specific set of bricks without going comparing one by one all the shops to see wich one has the mos amount of bricks etc?

If you have curiosity, I want to build the [mini LHC](http://build-your-own-particle-detector.org/models/lhc-micro-models/lhc-micro-models-parts-lists#fullset)

Comment: Also take a looke at: "[How can I minimize the number of merchants for given set of requested bricks?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/555/how-can-i-minimize-the-number-of-merchants-for-given-set-of-requested-bricks?rq=1)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see my response to [this post](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6084/old-sets-new-bricks). Using the Wanted List feature you can upload your own list of bricks and then see which vendors have these items - you would still need to fill a shopping cart at each vendor to see their price, but that is not so difficult by using the "add Minimum quantity" link at the top of the individual shop page.

Comment: Hum, I have been triying. Let me try to upload that XML file with IDs, its a very counterintuitive web page

Comment: I agree - it takes some getting used to. What I do is I generate my list in a spreadsheet (Excel, OpenOffice) and have a formula that generates the XML tags for each brick. I then paste the XML file into the textbox on the Wanted List page, and from there on it is fairly easy sailing.

Comment: Well I am having a problem while creating the XML file. It doesn't find any of the IDs in the catalogue. However, if a manually pick any of them and go to the search bar and search in the catalogue there is never a problem. Is there something I need to take into account while creating the XML? I knwo that IDs like `306223` are 4dig piece 2dig colour, so I can break down that ID into ID and colour for the XML but I have no idea of what to do with `6037390`.

Comment: Let me open a new more specific quesion.

Comment: 6037390 is 3007 in black, according to Bricklink: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3007&ccName=6037390

Comment: Yes, but the whole point of the question is so I dont need to manually go putting then one by one, and unfortunately, I dont have the 3007 black info, just the other. Check my other question to see additional problems in the XML

Comment: @Ander: Maybe you should try BrickOwl, and specifically their import function (http://www.brickowl.com/wishlist/import). I have not worked with it, but perhaps this works better for the list of IDs you have.

Comment: It seems interesting, however that would need me to use some other software where I would need to insert probably mnually or again programing another format and then load theyr formats and then use what Brickowl would give... It seems not the most straigthforward way! however thanks for the tip ;)